# How do I make the ZXing 4.4 bar code scanner go directly to a URL"?

Tags: android, zxing

I created a QR for the URL of a specific web page using the QRDroid app on my Android based smart phone.  I then scanned the QR image two different ways: (1) using the "scan" option of QRDroid and (2) using the ZXing bar code scanner 4.4.  In case (1), as soon as the scanner recognized the URL, it took me directly to the web page.  In case (2), the scanner took me to an intermediate display showing the URL hyperlink and some other information. In order to go to the web page represented by the link I had to either touch a "button" labeled "open browser" or touch the displayed URL link.

Is there any way to configure the ZXing scanner so that it takes the user directly to the web page rather than presenting the user with a hyperlink?  The QRDroid scanner gives the user a choice in its "setup" menu -- "ask me" vs "open URL" -- but I do not see a similar choice of options for ZXing 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

No, for security reasons, Barcode Scanner (this is the name of the app) will never automatically open a URL. By default. You can set it to do so in Settings, but it's a user choice. EDIT: actually this setting is not in the open source project at the moment.

Comment: I can not find the setting in "Barcode Scanner". I'm using version 5.6.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S2. Where is this?

Comment: Oops, I mixed this up with "Barcode Scanner +". I really don't recommend it so am reluctant to put this in the mainstream app, although it's easy. I put it in the for-pay app under the theory that, hey, you can have what you want for your $3. Which isn't the best theory...

Comment: Thanks. Too bad. I am developing a game with QR Codes to scan (along the lines of tiptoi, but simpler), and tapping the button each time is a game-killer.

Comment: Hm. OK, maybe will add this then. If it's off by default and people know what they're doing...

Comment: I just bought the "Barcode Scanner +" and can confirm it works perfectly, including the option to directly open the URL.

Comment: @SeanOwen hey, did you manage to add option to automatically start an url?